# php file becomes empty at certain moment

Tags: php, file, php-7.1

I am trying to save records into a file and when the file becomes bigger than 10MB, new file should be created. (This process happens concurrently. This is the reason that I used file lock)

However, the file becomes empty when it becomes 100KB. (It does not make any new file, but starts an empty file with same name.)

What is the problem in my code? Would `file_get_contents` on a locked file return `null`?
Any advice or suggestion would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

```
    $archiveSaveContents = [];
    $archiveSaveContents = 'some record';
    $archiveFileExtension = 'json';
    $archiveFilePath = FCPATH.'atch/driver_archive_location/'.$d->format('Y-m-d').'/'.$reqDate->format('H').'/';

    $archiveFiles = scandir($archiveFilePath);
    $archiveFiles = array_diff(scandir($archiveFilePath), array('.', '..'));

    $archiveFilePostfix = ( count($archiveFiles) <= 1 ) ? 1 : count($archiveFiles);

    $archiveFileName = DEVELOP_HOST.'_'.'driversLocation_'.$archiveFilePostfix.'.'.$archiveFileExtension;
    $archiveFullPath = $archiveFilePath.$archiveFileName;

    $archiveLimitSize = 10;
    $archiveFileSize = ( filesize($archiveFullPath ) * .0009765625) * .0009765625;

    if ( $archiveFileSize > $archiveLimitSize ) {
        $archiveFilePostfix = ( $archiveFilePostfix + 1 );
        $archiveFileName = DEVELOP_HOST.'_'.'driversLocation_'.$archiveFilePostfix.'.'.$archiveFileExtension;
        $archiveFullPath = $archiveFilePath.$archiveFileName;
    }

    $archiveFile = json_decode(file_get_contents($archiveFullPath),true);
    $archiveFile[] = $archiveSaveContents;

    if ( !is_dir($archiveFilePath) ) {
        @mkdir($archiveFilePath, 0777, TRUE);
        @chmod($archiveFilePath, 0777);
    }

    // if ( !$fp = @fopen($archiveFullPath, FOPEN_WRITE_CREATE) ) {
    if ( !$fp = @fopen($archiveFullPath, 'w+') ) {
        if ( false === $fp ) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Unable to open log file for writing');
        }

        return FALSE;
    }

    flock($fp, LOCK_EX);

    $write = fwrite($fp,json_encode($archiveFile));

    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);

    fclose($fp);

    @chmod($archiveFullPath, FILE_WRITE_MODE);
```

EDITED CODE: I suspected unsafe lock on file. So I have used safe lock on a file. But it still gives me same error. Then I found that in the process of writing file, the string which in form of json in the file gets corrupted while writing.

```
    $archiveFileName = DEVELOP_HOST.'_'.'driversLocation_'.$archiveFilePostfix.'.'.$archiveFileExtension;
    $archiveFullPath = $archiveFilePath.$archiveFileName;

    if ( !is_dir($archiveFilePath) ) {
        @mkdir($archiveFilePath, 0777, TRUE);
        @chmod($archiveFilePath, 0777);
    }

    $archiveLimitSize = 10;
    $archiveFileSize = ( filesize($archiveFullPath ) * .0009765625) * .0009765625;

    if ( $archiveFileSize > $archiveLimitSize ) {
        $archiveFilePostfix = ( $archiveFilePostfix + 1 );
        $archiveFileName = DEVELOP_HOST.'_'.'driversLocation_'.$archiveFilePostfix.'.'.$archiveFileExtension;
        $archiveFullPath = $archiveFilePath.$archiveFileName;
    }

    $readFp = fopen($archiveFullPath, 'r');

    if ( $readFp ) {
        while (!flock($readFp, LOCK_SH)) { usleep(1); }
        $contents = fread($readFp, filesize($archiveFullPath));
        flock($readFp, LOCK_UN);
        fclose($readFp);

        if ( !$fp = @fopen($archiveFullPath, 'r+') ) {
            if ( false === $fp ) {
                throw new RuntimeException('Unable to open log file for writing');
            }

            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    else {
        if ( !$fp = @fopen($archiveFullPath, 'w+') ) {
            if ( false === $fp ) {
                throw new RuntimeException('Unable to open log file for writing');
            }

            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    $archiveFile = json_decode($contents);
    $archiveFile[] = $archiveSaveContents;

    $pieces = str_split(json_encode($archiveFile), 1024 * 4);

    while (!flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) { usleep(1); }
    foreach ( $pieces as $piece ) {
        fwrite($fp, $piece, strlen($piece));
    }
    fflush($fp);
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
    fclose($fp);

    @chmod($archiveFullPath, FILE_WRITE_MODE);
```

Comment: Without fully understanding your code yet, the issues seem quite obvious to me: 1) Your calculation is wrong. That's why it's 100KB and not 10MB. And 2), you're not using a different filename, hence it overwrites the old one instead of creating a new one.

Comment: @icecub Why is my calculation is wrong? `filesize()` returns bytes which would be converted if divided by 1024^2. And when the limit is over, I use different postfix which is used for filename.

Comment: put in some debug `echo` statements so you can verify the variables contents. Thats always a good approach if a program doesnt behave as expected.